# UITableView - unexpectedly found nil Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

i have a problem. I'm having a tableview from where i try to populate with some firebase data, but i have an error to my labels. " Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an optional".In the console, is appearing that the labels are nil. i have connected my iboutlets correctly and i have set the "reuseIdentifier" in the inspector. Im using prototype cells.

My full class :

```
struct Info {
    var address: String
    var name: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    
}

class InfoViewController: UITableViewController
{
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    
    var info: [Info] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCartProducts()
        self.tableView.register(InfoTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        
        navigationItem.title = "Profilul meu"
        
        
        
    }
    func getCartProducts() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        db.collection("Users").document(userID).getDocument{  (document, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                if let  document = document {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Info(address: data!["address"] as! String, name: data!["name"] as! String , phoneNumber: data!["phoneNumber"] as! String
                    )
                    
        
                    self.info.append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //  self.datas = self.filteredData
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return info.count
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InfoTableViewCell
        let infos = info[indexPath.row]
        cell.numeL.text = infos.name
        cell.adresaL.text = infos.address
        cell.telefonL.text = infos.phoneNumber
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    

}
```

And my Cell class, if that helps too :

```
class InfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var adresaL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numeL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var telefonL: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The error is at the :

```
 cell.numeL.text = infos.name
        cell.adresaL.text = infos.address
        cell.telefonL.text = infos.phoneNumber
```

Comment: Unwrapping with `!` and `as!` is inherently dangerous and can cause this crash. Look at all of the places that you're using it and learn to use `if let` and `guard let` ("optional binding") to handle situations where you might have a `nil` value. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: You don't need `DispatchQueue.main.async {` in Firebase closures; UI calls are always done on the main thread. Also do this `self.tableView.register(InfoTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)` before loading the data from firebase and refreshing the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using prototype cells, there must be *no* `tableView.register` code at all. Delete it.

Double check the table view controller inspector in the storyboard. Make sure it has the correct class.

Then check its prototype cell inspector in the storyboard. Make sure it has the correct class. Then make sure it has the correct outlets from the labels.

Comment: It have the correct classes and the identity inspector for the cell is correct too. Really dont know what's wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You need to register cell properly

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"InfoTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

Set identifier here

[image]

Comment: Thaank you for your answear, i have got the following error using your code : Could not load NIB in bundle:

Comment: Do you have `InfoTableViewCell.xib` ? or  cell inside the table ? if inside the table then remove the register line completely

Comment: Im using prototype cells. I have tried to delete the register line, but i have got an error :  "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier  "

Comment: Is set, but still get the error, also the cell class  is set correctly too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
let newEntry = Info(address: data!["address"] as! String, name: data!["name"] as! String , phoneNumber: data!["phoneNumber"] as! String)
```

you have to use some thing like this

```
guard let address = data?["address"] as? String else {return}
guard let  name = data?["name"] as? String else {return}
guard let phoneNumber = data?["phoneNumber"] as? String else {return}
let newEntry = Info(address: address, name: name , phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
```

this method will safely unwrap your data but remember if each of them is null you will not have any data so it's better to set a default value in the firebase data base to avoid that problem

also for your table view function
instead of

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InfoTableViewCell
```

use

```
 guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? InfoTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
```

in this case of your cell identifier doesn't write correct your app will not crash at least

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I have used a .xib file and now is working. Really dont know why it wasn't working with the prototype cells.